# How to short on desending order using a object property using parseFloat?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have the following [test code](http://jsfiddle.net/9newe639/1/)

```
var arr = [{
    EmployeeInfo: [{
        annualWage: "24000"
    }],
    name: "Tim",
    surname: "Jones",
    id: "1111"
}, {
    EmployeeInfo: [{
        annualWage: "52000"
    }],
    name: "Terry",
    surname: "Phillips",
    id: "2222"
}];

console.log(arr);

arr.sort(function (a, b) {

    return parseFloat(a.EmployeeInfo[0].annualWage) - parseFloat(b.EmployeeInfo[0].annualWage);
});

console.log(arr);
```

I want to sort the array by annualWage with the highest earner at the beginning. 
Can't seem to get it to work... what obvious thing am I missing?

Comment: You need to return either a or b, not the subtraction of something.

Comment: @NeilMunro — What? No. You need to return a number that is either 0, positive or negative.

Comment: Yeah, sorry my bad! Totally ignore me, I'm talking out the wrong end!

Comment: So if the highest is at the end, what do you think is wrong with the check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to reverse the order. **[The rules](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/array/sort)** are as follows:

> If `compareFunction` is supplied, the array elements are sorted according to the return value of the compare function. If a and b are two elements being compared, then:
>
> - **If `compareFunction(a, b)` is less than 0, sort a to a lower index than b, i.e. a comes first.**
> - **If `compareFunction(a, b)` returns 0, leave a and b unchanged with respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all different
>     elements.** Note: the ECMAscript standard does not guarantee this
>     behaviour, and thus not all browsers (e.g. Mozilla versions dating
>     back to at least 2003) respect this.
> - **If `compareFunction(a, b)` is greater than 0, sort b to a lower index than a.**
> - `compareFunction(a, b)` must always return the same value when given a specific pair of elements a and b as its two arguments. If
>     inconsistent results are returned then the sort order is undefined.

So basically:

```
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return parseFloat(b.EmployeeInfo[0].annualWage) - parseFloat(a.EmployeeInfo[0].annualWage);
});
```

Comment: thanks, i knew it was something simple... the descriptios above really help

Answer (score 0):

You're sorting it backwards and putting the lowest earner at the beginning.

Swap `a` and `b` in your compare function.

```
return parseFloat(b.EmployeeInfo[0].annualWage) -     parseFloat(a.EmployeeInfo[0].annualWage);
```

Comment: @vtz Wasn't me, although I suspect it's the lack of explanation that did it for this and your answer.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha hm thats a relief, I +1 your answer because of the explanation but the other answers are not incorrect. This is stupud....

Answer (score 0):

There you go,
swapped a and b and no need for float

```
arr.sort(function(a, b) {

  return parseInt(b.EmployeeInfo[0].annualWage) - parseInt(a.EmployeeInfo[0].annualWage);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

here is my solution how im doing sort:

```
a.sort(function (x, y) { return ((x > y) - (y > x)) * d; });
```

where `d == 1` for ascending sort and `d==-1` for descending

Comment: It seems you are assuming that the function should return 1 , 0 or -1 whereas negative , positive or zero suffice.  Just as info :  the -1 vote is not mine.

Comment: @Peter i bet -1 is for that its more hint than answer

Comment: yes, some very strict judger @ work on all answers apparantly :)